# Does "git commit files" put files to the staging area?

Tags: git, addition, commit

In [a Visual Git Reference](http://marklodato.github.io/visual-git-guide/index-en.html) I read that it is possible to commit some local changes by jumping over the staging area. For that one need to use `git commit files`. In other words one do not need to use `git add`. However, it is not clear to me if this command will add the changes to the staging area. Can one say that `git commit files` is equivalent to combination of `git add files` and `git commit`? Or, is it correct to say, that the changes are written directly to the history without being saved in the staging area?

Comment: Possible indicator: If you abort the commit the staging area is unmodified. But sincerely its an ~atomic operation why does it matter?

Answer (score 0):

What you're searching for is `git commit -a`: that adds all the changes to the staging area (IIRC new files won't get committed though but I'm not sure about that).